# Java JpaRepository @Query join own table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class where each instance can have a parent of the same type.

Now I want to be able to delete a parent object, and in the process delete all its children with it. I couldn't do it via a cascade type so I made a custom query in my JPA repository. Unfortunately this bean could not be created because the custom query has some kind of error.

> **Entity** class

```
@Entity
@Transactional
@Table(name = "bericht")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Embeddable
public class Bericht implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Bericht parent;
}
```

> **Repository** interface

```
@Transactional
public interface BerichtRepository extends JpaRepository<Bericht, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT b1 FROM Bericht b join Bericht b1 WHERE b1.parent.id <> NULL AND b1.parent.id = b.id AND b.id = ?1 order by b1.id desc")
    public List<Bericht> getChildrenVanBericht(Integer id);

    public default void deleteBericht(Integer id) {
        List<Bericht> kinderen = getChildrenVanBericht(id);

        for(Bericht kind:kinderen) {
            if(getChildrenVanBericht(kind.getId()).size()==0) {
                this.delete(kind);
            } else {
                deleteBericht(kind.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As seen I want to start deleting from the bottom of the hierarchy via the `deleteBericht` method and work upwards in the hierarchy to the top.

Is there a better solution out there than the `deleteBericht` method as shown above?

Comment: Do you have just a two-level hierarchy (parent and its children) or can the hierarchy be multi-level (parent, children, grandchildren, etc.)? If multi-level, should the deletes cascade to the entire tree under the node being deleted or just its immediate children (if only immediate children, what should happen to the grandchildren, etc.?)? Can a parent have more than one child (if yes, your parent-child mapping is incorrectly declared as `@OneToOne` instead of `@ManyToOne`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have some problems with your basic mapping. If it's an Entity it shouldn't have the `@Embeddable` annotation. Additionally, you shouldn't have `@Transactional` on an `@Entity`.

Anyway, I would expect that you should be able to delete in the normal way if you were to make the relationship bi-directional as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bericht")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Bericht implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.DELETE)
    private Bericht child;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Bericht parent;

    //additionally always ensure both sides of the relationship are consistent

    public void setChild(Bericht child){
       this.child = child;
       child.parent = this;
    }

    public void setParent(Bericht parent){
       this.parent = parent;
       parent.child = this;
    }
}
```

Now when deleting a Bericht instance any children should be deleted automatically.

```
Bericht b = //some Bericht
berichtRepository.delete(b);// should cascade down through all children
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to avoid recurcivity, it's always risky.

I purpose you an other solution, get the list of all the `kind.id` then make an SQL delete like `Query s = entytiManager.createQuery("Delete * From KindTable k Where k.id In ( :kIdLst )");` and provide kIdLst through `q.setList("kIdLst", kindIds);`

Good luck !
Z

Comment: recursion ... risky? huh? I use recursive relations in my classes with 0 problems. Any JPA provider worth its money should be able to handle such basic things

Comment: The risk of the recursion isn't linked to JPA, it's linked to the fact that if you haven’t a full and definitive control on the volume of data you have to process in your recursive method, you're risking some out of memory, or stack full. Another point is in the case if you do recursively, and if you have 100 kind, you'll call 100 sql request and the growth of the number of request is linear with the number of kind (I.e.: 100k => 100sql, 1000k => 1000sql, and so on) ; without recursion, you'll call just one request whatever the number of kind...